# Strange error from Google API: initializeAutocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

A screenshot is attached since I'm not even sure how to describe the error.

[image]

It claims `initializeAutocomplete` is not a function, yet the function clearly exists in my JS file and here it is...

```
let autocomplete

function initializeAutocomplete() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(addressInput, {
    types: ['geocode']
  })
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', parseAddress)
}
```

And here is the reference in my HTML file to the script.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
v=3
&key=[confidential]
&libraries=places
&callback=initializeAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

I'm at a loss, especially since this started happening out of nowhere. Does anybody know what's happening here?

Comment: Wow. Now it all of a sudden started working again and I didn't even touch it. I'm still interested to know what's going on if anybody has any idea whatsoever. Never mind, now it started bugging out again... WTF

Comment: it works. then doesn't. it works. then doesn't. it works. then doesn't...

Comment: Can you constantly reproduce  it if you isolate it in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: Can you at less, display all your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `async` and `defer` [script attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script). Your script is probably loaded after the one calling the `initializeAutocomplete` function.

Comment: that's precisely what was happening. i had figured it out in the meantime